# How do I display elements like the cart in a Panels page?

Tags: 6, ubercart, panels

How can I use the Ubercart cart in a Panels page? I do not see it under any of the Contents list.

I think I am looking for a Drupal 6 version of [uc_panels](http://drupal.org/project/uc_panels).

Answer (score 0):

The uc_panels module is a D7 port of the code in this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/658732) which is a D6 panels integration for Ubercart. See comment #49 and the patch in #69.

Give it a try.